# Field extension of quotient field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

$1$. Let $ F $ be a field and $a,b$ be nonzero element in $L/F$.

How to show that a field extension $F(a,b)/F(a^{−1}b^{−1},a+b)$ is an algebraic extension?

I tried to show all element in $F(a,b)$ is an algeraic over $F(a^{−1}b^{−1},a+b)$ but

I failed....

$2$. Compute $[F(x):F(x^2/(x−1))]$ ($F$ is also a field)

$F(x)$ is a quotient field of $F[x]$, polynomial ring over $F$.

Comment: If $a,b \in F$ then $F(a,b) = F$ or what do you mean by $F(a,b)$? (the function field in the variables $a,b$?)

Comment: @BISHD It;s mistake... they are element of L which is a field extension of F

Comment: So you mean by $F(a,b)$ the smallest field that contains $F$ and $a,b$? (Then it is usually denoted by $F[a,b]$) Why would $F(a,b) / F(a^-1 b^-1, a+b)$ be an extension anyway?

Comment: @BISHD: "Then it is usually denoted by $F[a,b]$" - No, this is the smallest $F$-subalgebra containing $a$ and $b$.This agrees with $F(a,b)$ iff $a,b$ are algebraic.

Comment: Yeah, $F[a,b]$ is just a ring not a field.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Sorry, I was wrong with this! So for solving the first question, you have to show that an arbitrary element of $F(a,b)$ is a root of a polynomial with coefficients in $F(a^-1 b^-1, a+b)$.

Comment: This would be quite hard, but it is enough to show that the generators $a,b$ are algebraic (since algebraic elements constitute a subfield).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some hints.

1. Look at the roots of $T^2 - (a+b)T + ab$. Conclude that $a,b$ are algebraic over $F(ab,a+b) = F(a^{-1} b^{-1},a+b)$.
2. If $a=x^2/(x-1)$, then $x^2 - a (x-1) = 0$. Prove that $T^2-a(T-1)$ is the minimal polynomial of $x$ over $F(a)$.

Comment: 1. It means $[F(ab,a+b)(a):F(ab,a+b)]$ is finite, and $F(ab,a+b)(a)=F(ab,a,b)$? If then, algebraic b is not needed?

Comment: Oh, thanks very very much for your help :)